# RecyclerView with DiffCallback don't show up anything

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, listadapter

- I have a fragment that contains a recycler view, those code below are the implementation. I learn it exactly from the android basic in kotlin from google developer. Somehow the recycler view won't show up anything.
- I have also check for the data list that pass to the recycler view and everything look just fine.
  Here is the Android Project from github: https://github.com/sonsonson110/My_Weather_App/tree/(unstable)new_things
- Some important file to check: DaysDetailAdapter, BindingAdapter, WeatherDetailFragment, WeatherFragmentViewModel, fragment_weather_detail.xml, weather_detail_item.xml
- I know that it is long but if you have your free time, please help a beginner me :( thanks!

**Binding Adapter**

```
    @BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<Forecastday>?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as DaysDetailAdapter
    adapter.submitList(data)
}
```

**RecyclerView adapter**

```
class DaysDetailAdapter :
    ListAdapter<Forecastday, DaysDetailAdapter.DaysDetailViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    class DaysDetailViewHolder(private var binding: WeatherDetailItemBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(forecastday: Forecastday) {
            binding.day = forecastday
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Forecastday>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Forecastday, newItem: Forecastday): Boolean {
            return oldItem.dateEpoch == newItem.dateEpoch
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Forecastday, newItem: Forecastday): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DaysDetailViewHolder {
        return DaysDetailViewHolder(
            WeatherDetailItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DaysDetailViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val forecastday = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(forecastday)
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView XML**

```
...
<data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.myweatherapp.overview.WeatherFragmentViewModel" />
</data>
...
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/weather_detail_item"
            tools:itemCount="4"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.forecastdayList}">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**RV Item XML**

```
...
<data>
        <variable
            name="day"
            type="com.example.myweatherapp.model.Forecastday" />
</data>
...
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@{day.date}"/>
```

**Fragment that hold RV**

```
class WeatherDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    //shared view model
    private val sharedViewModel: WeatherFragmentViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = FragmentWeatherDetailBinding.inflate(inflater)

        sharedViewModel.getDaysData()

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = sharedViewModel
        binding.recyclerView.apply {
            adapter = DaysDetailAdapter()
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Edit:

After a few look at stackoverflow at the missing item in recycler view, i understand that the problem is at the adapter:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DaysDetailViewHolder {
        return DaysDetailViewHolder(
            WeatherDetailItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        )
    }
```

Still can anyone explain why the items goes away?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure, that your recycler view is not created?
(android:layout_width="0dp",android:layout_height="0dp"). It looks like you use a constraintlayout, remove these lines.
By the way details is written with s.

Comment: @winter_chris: I have a parent constraint layout which is already set to match parent, sorry for the lack, I just want to show the important information